# read xml nodes using java code

Tags: java, xml, windows

i am connecting to database of many servers to retrieve data from them all, i am using xml file contains the information of each database server [ip,port,user,passwd] followed by the query to be executed on that server. i read the queries in my code as arrayList and get them one by one to be processed. what i need is a clear simple code to also read the database server info to connect to it and execute the relative query , i.e. for each a query i need to get the database IP,port,user,passwd in my code. here is my xml file structure. thanks in adavnce.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Database>
<DB>
<ip></ip>
<port></port>
<user></user>
<pass></pass>
</DB>
<Query>
select date from myTable
</Query>
<DB>
<ip></ip>
<port></port>
<user></user>
<pass></pass>
</DB>
<Query>
select time from myTable
</Query>
<DB>
<ip></ip>
<port></port>
<user></user>
<pass><></pass>
</DB>
<Query>
select name from myTable
</Query>
</Database>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java's DOM api for xml processing and xpath.

- DOM: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/index.html
- Xpath: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp

Below is some sample code that does part of what you want (extracts the ip and port). You will need to modify it to do the rest:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


public class DomTester {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws  ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, XPathExpressionException {

        InputStream inStr = null;
        try {
            String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"
                    + "<Database>"
                    +   "<DB>"
                    +       "<ip>666</ip>"
                    +       "<port>7</port>"
                    +   "</DB>"
                    +   "<DB>"
                    +   "   <ip>13</ip>"
                    +       "<port>1</port>"
                    +   "</DB>"
                    + "</Database>";

            inStr = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder(); 
            Document doc = db.parse(inStr);

            XPathFactory xFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xpath = xFactory.newXPath();
            XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/Database");
            Element databaseEl = (Element)expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);

            NodeList databaseNodeList = databaseEl.getChildNodes();
            for (int ii=0; ii<databaseNodeList.getLength(); ++ii) {
                Node dbNode = databaseNodeList.item(ii);
                XPathExpression ipExpr = xpath.compile("ip");
                Element ipElement = (Element)ipExpr.evaluate(dbNode, XPathConstants.NODE);
                String ip = ipElement.getTextContent();

                XPathExpression portExpr = xpath.compile("port");
                Element portEl = (Element)portExpr.evaluate(dbNode, XPathConstants.NODE);
                String port = portEl.getTextContent();

                System.out.println("DB node[" + ii + "] = ip: " + ip + " port: " + port);
            }
        } finally {
            if (null != inStr) {
                inStr.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since you are reading from a file instead of using a string, instead of doing this:

```
inStr = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());
```

do this:

```
File f = new File("your/file/path.xml");
inStr = new FileInputStream(f);
```